# Make a link to DIV on site only

Tags: iframe, html, hyperlink, server-side-includes

Is it possible to link to ONLY a div on a web page? For example,

```
<html>
    <body>
        Here is some content I don't care about
        <div class="stuff">
            Here is some content I want. Blah blah. It may change from time to time
        </div>
        Here is more content I don't care about and do not want to see when this link is clicked
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a hyperlink that will display only the contents of "stuff" with nothing else?

For further clarification, if someone were to make an  of this link, nothing else from that page would appear in the iframe.

Comment: Are you talking about linking to the content on the page (like an anchor) or displaying ONLY the contents of that div?

Comment: I have to ask, why would you want to do this? Why not just create a page that only has what you want to display on it?

Comment: only to the contents of the div. the reason is that I have ~70 pages, all linked to by a single page. I want that single page to contain the first little blurb of information from each of the ~70 pages. I don't want to hard code it because I want it to update as I update that blurb in the div

Comment: I was considering attempting a SSI or iframe of the contents of THOSE divs in the parent page.

Comment: This doesn't technically *answer* the question, but as long as you don't care about the person being able to scroll and seeing the other information, you could just use named anchors.

Comment: At 70 pages I'd be looking for a database'd solution rather than static pages, then the issue becomes moot as you'll just pull the 'blurb' rather than the main content for your summary page.

Comment: loading all the content from every page might be a bit too much of a bandwidth hog. it probably wouldn't be aesthetically pleasing either.

Comment: You could maybe run it through an XSLT script that strips out everything but the desired div?  Not that I have any idea how to do that or how reliably it would work.

Comment: yeah I was thinking a database might be the answer, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to be copy+pasting this afternoon.

Comment: @thomas - Check out Pat's answer below, it's spot on given your current architecture but would require a lot of cutting and pasting I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) call to get that fragment of your page and load it on your single page:

```
$('#result').load('your-page.html .stuff');
```

Comment: I wish I could +10 this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: No

The longer answer involves a bunch of JavaScript on the page where the content is to be hidden (i.e. you couldn't do it to a third party site, and if it is your own site you would almost certainly be better off just creating a separate URI you could call)